# Symbolic Integration returns garbage

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I have the following integral, which I have computed via other sources to match a given solution. However, SymPy returns something that appears to be garbage. Why is this happening? Have I not explicitly established something that Mathematica and Integral Calculator assume?

```
from sympy import symbols, integrate, oo
x, z = symbols('x,z')
expr = 1/((x**2 + z**2)**(3/2))
integrate(expr, (x,-oo,oo))
```

Gives the following result:

[image]

I know the result to be: 2/(z^2)

As I don't know how (or if it's even possible) to enter LaTeX here, below is the operation attempted and desired result

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `**(3 / 2)` which is a `float`. This is an issue that `SymPy` struggles with and is one of the issues mentioned here under [Gotchas and Pitfalls](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/gotchas.html#python-numbers-vs-sympy-numbers). I found this from the GitHub page [integrate((x-t)**(-1/2)*t,(t,0,x)) raises ValueError](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/14431#issuecomment-371594717).

You need to make sure that your exponent is a rational number. There are a few ways to do this. Below, we use `S` ([sympify](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.sympify.sympify)):

```
from sympy import symbols, integrate, oo, S
x, z = symbols('x,z')
expr = 1/((x**2 + z**2)**(S(3)/2))
integrate(expr, (x,-oo,oo))
```

Which gives the desired output.

Comment: Also setting assumptions like `real=True` or `positive=True` for the symbols can simplify many integrals.

Comment: This is certainly an unexpected use of `simplify`, and I'll take the bulk of my questions elsewhere, but why does this work? I briefly scanned the documentation for `simpilfy`, but nothing obvious popped out.

Comment: @Matt, it isn't `simplify`, it's `sympify`. I incorrectly wrote `simpify` (without the `l`). Sorry for the mistake. I added a link to docs to clarify.